# How do I order results by alternating (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,...) rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL to perform database transactions and PHP to run MySQL queries. I want to fetch the query result by this sequence using value of `is_free` column (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,...). I want to fetch records by a ratio like 3:6 for the value of `is_free` column.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

I've searched for different algorithms but nothing is found as per my requirement. I've found the only query which throws result by alternative records but my requirement not fulfilled.

I expect the output like

```
id     is_free
--     -------
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
10     0
11     0
12     0
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: May be `ORDER BY FIELD` would help.

Comment: @Nick - I'm using MySQL 5.7.24

Comment: @SougataBose - `ORDER BY FIELD` is not working for me because of it's working on the only 1st position. If I used that then they will give records like (0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,..). So it will filter the records by 0 & 1 not as per my requirement.

Comment: Yes, in this case it will not.

Comment: If `id` is indeed part of your output then it seems your data is already sorted in the way you want it. To get it simply use `ORDER BY id`.

Comment: @PinalPatel I will try and let you know, it's tricky.

Comment: Post the sample input as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need something similar to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY is_free ORDER BY id)`. Once you have the row numbers for each partition (e.g. 0-0, 0-1, 0-2, 0-3, ..., 1-0, 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, ...) you can use basic math to sort the results (values 0-0...0-2 and 1-0...1-5 go first, 0-3...0-5 and 1-6...1-11 go second and so on). Unfortunately MySQL 5.x does not support window functions so you need to calculate row numbers using some kind of trick. Here is one:

```
SELECT *
     , rn div IF(is_free = 1, 6, 3) AS gn
FROM (
    SELECT id
         , is_free
         , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS x WHERE x.id < t.id AND x.is_free = t.is_free) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS x
ORDER BY gn, is_free
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=407798e8779003df324962ef4a85c2b0)

Comment: Cool! Especially `rn` calculation +1 Don't you need order by id?

Comment: @splash the current order by clause is sufficient to put the 1s and 0s in sequence.

Comment: Im about rn calculation SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS x WHERE x.id < t.id  ... ?

Comment: Nope, `COUNT(*)` means it is an implicit `GROUP BY` query that returns exactly one or zero rows... no ordering required.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use:

```
order by floor( (row_number() over (partition by is_free order by id) - 1) / 4),
         is_free, id
```

The arithmetic on `row_number()` batches them.  You can do something similar with variables in earlier versions:

```
select t.id, t.is_free
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@if = is_free, @rn + 1,
                        if(@if := is_free, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.* from t order by is_free, id) t cross join
           (select @if := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
order by floor((rn - 1) / 4), is_free, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,is_free,rank
from (
         (
            select id,is_free,if(@row_num = @target,@target := @target + 9,@target := @target + 0) as target,if(@target - @row_num > 3,@row_num := @row_num + 7,@row_num := @row_num + 1) as rank
            from test,(select @row_num := 0,@target := 3) t2
            where is_free = 0
         )
        union
          (
            select id,is_free,if(@row_num2 = @target2,@target2 := @target2 + 9,@target2 := @target2 + 0) as target,if(@target2 - @row_num2 > 8,@row_num2 := @row_num2 + 4,@row_num2 := @row_num2 + 1) as rank
            from test,(select @row_num2 := 3,@target2 := 9) t3
            where is_free = 1
          )
) derived
order by rank,is_free,id;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pc9oCwwtWjacETVeGCMtcw/0

- The idea above is to give a `rank` to every row in such a way that we could maintain a 3:6 ratio.
- If we closely observe, the `0`'s follow the series of ranks as `1 , 2 , 3 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 19 , 20 , 21` and `1`'s follow the series of `4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23 ...`  as shown below:

**Series:**

```
0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

- So, in the above query, we first fetch all records of `0` and assign row numbers to them in the above fashion starting from `1`. We then fetch all records of is_free = `1` in the same manner by assigning row numbers starting from `4`.
- In the end, we combine both results using union and order them by their ranks.